# Change value of variable from component to other (non related components)

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-components, eventemitter

Is there a way to change the value of the variable called `variable1` in the ***component 2*** from ***component 1*** making click in the function of this component ?

***Component 1 ts***

```
@Component({
  selector:    'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.html',
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit {
  changeVariable(){
      
  }
}
```

***component1.html***

```
<div (click)="changeVariable()"></div>
```

***Component 2 ts***

```
@Component({
  selector:    'app-component2',
  templateUrl: './component2.html',
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
  variable1: boolean = false
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: But these components are not parent and child, that is the thing..

Comment: check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990900/angular-5-change-variable-from-another-component)

Comment: The service option does not require the parent-child relationship, depending on where the service is provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 - change variable from another Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990900/angular-5-change-variable-from-another-component)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Pass the component2 context/reference into component1.
2. Use service to store the variable1, and it can be then share between component1 and component2.

---

#### Option 1

If non-related means sibling components which is used side by side in a parent component like below:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <app-component-1>   </app-component-1>
  <app-component-2>   </app-component-2>
</div>
```

Then you can pass the context of the component-2 into component-1.

**component1.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Component2Component } from '../component-2/component-2.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-1',
  templateUrl: './component-1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-1.component.css']
})
export class Component1Component {

  // This will allow you to pass in component2 context/reference.
  @Input()
  public component2Context!: Component2Component;

  constructor() { }

  public changeVariable() {
    // After passing component2 context, you can call all its public functions/properties.
    this.component2Context.variable1 = true;
  }

}
```

**component1.html**

```
<button (click)="changeVariable()">Change Variable 1</button>
```

**component2.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-2',
  templateUrl: './component-2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-2.component.css'],
})
export class Component2Component {
  public variable1 = false;

  constructor() {}
}
```

**component2.html**

```
<div>Component2.variable1 = {{ variable1 }}</div>
```

Then in the `Parent`, you need to pass the reference from component2 into the component1 like below:

**parent.html**

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <app-component-1 [component2Context]="comp2Context"></app-component-1>
  <app-component-2 #comp2Context></app-component-2>
</div>
```

---

#### Option 2

You can use a service to store the `variable1`. Then any components can have access to it. Component1 can update its value, and component2 can see the updated value.

Here is the demo I created: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qj7mer